# How to declare function pointer in header and c-file?

Tags: c, function, pointers, header, prototype-programming

I'm a little confused over how to declare a function pointer in a header file.
I want to use it in main and a file called menus.c and declare it in menus.h I assume.
We want to initialize to point to a certain function.

it looks like this:

```
void (*current_menu)(int);
```

What do we write in menus.c, menus.h and main?

Answer (score 25):

A function pointer is still a pointer, meaning it's still a variable.

If you want a variable to be visible from several source files, the simplest solution is to declare it `extern` in a header, with the definition elsewhere.

**In a header:**

```
extern void (*current_menu)(int);
```

**In one source file:**

```
void (*current_menu)(int) = &the_func_i_want;
```

Comment: the ampersand isn't strictly necessary

Comment: That is true, @Dave.  In C, it's a stylistic choice of mine for clarity.  In C++ it's sometimes required in certain template contexts, so I just do it for consistency.

Comment: @DrewDormann I thought `extern` was redundant. Shouldn't it be globally visible without  specifying `extern`?

Comment: @Geremia [How do I use extern to share variables between source files in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204)

Answer (score 8):

It's often helpful to use `typedef` with function pointers, so you can name the type to something descriptive:

```
typedef void (*MenuFunction)(int);
```

Then you would have a global variable of this type, probably in menus.c, and declared (with `extern`) in menus.h:

```
static void my_first_menu_function(int x)
{
  printf("the menu function got %d\n", x);
}

MenuFunction current_menu = my_first_menu_function;
```

From main.c, you can then do:

```
#include "menu.h"

current_menu(4711);
```

to call whatever function is currently pointed at by `current_menu`.

Comment: Very true!  `function<void(int)>` is also available if you have access to boost or C++11.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer function itself does not have a function definition.  It's nothing more than a pointer to a type, the type being specified by the return type of the function and the parameter list.  What you need to do is define a function with the same parameter list and return type, then use your pointer function to hold that function's address.  You can then call the function through the pointer.