# Linker warnings when using extern reference to a pointer-to-function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, extern

**Api.cpp:**

```
int (*theFunc) (int);
theFunc = (int (*) (int)) DlSym(hSo, "theFunc");
```

So far so good.

Now, I want to make a header so that other cpp files can also call theFunc.

---

**Api.h:** per [How to declare function pointer in header and c-file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562694/how-to-declare-function-pointer-in-header-and-c-file)

```
extern int (*theFunc)(int);
```

> /usr/bin/ld: Warning: type of symbol `theFunc' changed from 2 to 1 in Api.o

OK, so this is a warning that theFunc is seen as a function from one compilation element and as a variable in another.  [(Reference)](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2008-03/msg00269.html) This seems like bad things will happen at runtime.

This seems to be a proper declaration, what am I doing wrong?

*Edit:  Actually running in linux, so use DlSym not Microsoft GetProcAddress() call*

Comment: How about adding `typedef`. `extern typedef int (*theFunc)(int);`

Answer (score 0):

According to the linked post, condense it to one line, not two in the .cpp file.  So the .h seems right, and put this in the .cpp file:

```
int (*theFunc) (int) = (int (*) (int)) GetProcAddress(hDll, "theFunc");
```

You're not doing declaration and assignment in one shot like the linked answer is.  With what I posted above, you will be.

Comment: I can't call GetProcAddress from a variable definition, because I don't have a handle to the dll until runtime inside a function, after I've called LoadLibrary()

Comment: For "defining" the location of an extern variable like this, any assignment should work, so maybe try NULL-assigning the variable in the .cpp file, and then "really" assigning it later.

Comment: Initialization is not required for definition.  And that's not even the problem.  The variable is defined and it shows, I can find it it objdump -t just fine.  The problem is that in other compilation units,  extern int (*theFunc)(int); is seen as a function declaration, not a pointer-to-function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not include Api.h

Alternatively you may work with macros in a way that api.h behave somewhat different when included by api.cpp.
MicroSoft has done/do such things.

api.h

```
#ifdef _API_
#define EXTERN
#else
#define EXTERN extern
#endif

EXTERN int (*theFunc)(int);
```

api.cpp

```
#define _API_
#include "api.h"
...
```

other.cpp

```
#define _OTHER_
#include "api.h"
...
```

Comment: This warn occurs regardless of whether I do or don't include Api.h from Api.cpp.

Comment: Also, same results (ld warn) using your defines

Comment: And I'm using linux gcc, not MS, despite my original post.  Buried further in, I'm actually calling DlSym.  There's a stupid wrapper around this third party .so that uses MS function names to load the .so, they can be "Cross Platform"  Ugh.