# Void function declared in *.hxx, defined in *.cxx but undefined in *.c

Tags: c, function, gcc, header, undefined

I'm trying to declare a global function accessible through different *.c files.

I have declared it in param.hxx, defined it in param.cxx and I would like to access it in compute_grid.c.

Unfortunately, during the compilation I have the following error :

```
compute_grid.c:(.text+0x5) : undefined reference to « grid_create »
```

I'm not very familiar with such functions declarations in C. Actually I'm building a module part of a big program, I've copied those declaration from another file of the code witch seems to work ?!

Unfortunately, the program is hugely confidential, I don't have access to all the sources but I will do my best to give you expurged parts...

param.hxx :

```
typedef struct grid_t
{
    int   *test;
} grid_t;

void 
grid_create(void);

extern grid_t *grid;
```

param.cxx :

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include "param.hxx"

grid_t *grid;

void grid_create(void)
{
    grid = (grid_t*)malloc(sizeof(grid_t));
    grid->test = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *grid->test = 123;
}
```

compute_grid.c :

```
#include "param.hxx"

void
compute_grid()
{
    grid_create();

    return;
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What command(s) are you using to compile?

Comment: You need to compile both sources and link them together.  Perhaps that would be achieved by naming both (the .c and .cxx) on the compiler command line.

Comment: Question, however: what language do you expect the compiler to assume for file `param.cxx`?  If C, then its name should end in `.c`, not `.cxx`.

Comment: This part of the code is compiled with g++.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, unfortunately I can't modify the compiler call, which is unaccessible for me.
However, I don't think that it's a compiler linking problem (I'm surely wrong) : I tried the solution described here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562694/how-to-declare-function-pointer-in-header-and-c-file) an it worked, but once I adapt it to follow the rest of my code, nope, not anymore :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.cxx` is one of the extensions used for C++ files. Your compiler may be using the extension of the file to compile the source as C++. When the C file is compiled, it generates an unresolved reference to the C symbol `grid_create`, but the compiled C++ file defines `grid_create` as a C++ symbol. Thus, the linker will leave the C symbol reference to `grid_create` unresolved, since there is only a C++ symbol associated with `void grid_create(void)`.

You can try to guard the header file so that the C++ compiler will generate a C symbol rather than a C++ one.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void 
grid_create(void);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you it worked !! However I don't quite understand why in another groupe of header/*.c file already existing in the program I'm using, it worked with the same header declaration ?

Comment: Are the other C files calling `grid_create()`?

Comment: No, but a similarly defined function. Actually I copy/paste the header files for those other functions in a new header, and then simplifying this content to create my own function i.e. grid_create()

Comment: It is not clear if those C files face the same problem. If the symbols are resolving, then it means the linker found a defined symbol.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041866/315052 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/3789340/315052